# getting words between m and n characters

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get all names that start with a capital letter and ends with a full-stop on the same line where the number of characters are between 3 and 5

My text is as follows:

```
 King. Great happinesse

 Rosse. That now Sweno, the Norwayes King,
Craues composition:
Nor would we deigne him buriall of his men,
Till he disbursed, at Saint Colmes ynch,
Ten thousand Dollars, to our generall vse

 King. No more that Thane of Cawdor shall deceiue
Our Bosome interest: Goe pronounce his present death,
And with his former Title greet Macbeth

 Rosse. Ile see it done

 King. What he hath lost, Noble Macbeth hath wonne.
```

I am testing it out on this [link](http://pythex.org/?regex=l%7B3%2C5%7D&test_string=%0A%20King.%20Great%20happinesse%0A%0A%20Rosse.%20That%20now%20Sweno%2C%20the%20Norwayes%20King%2C%0ACraues%20composition%3A%0ANor%20would%20we%20deigne%20him%20buriall%20of%20his%20men%2C%0ATill%20he%20disbursed%2C%20at%20Saint%20Colmes%20ynch%2C%0ATen%20thousand%20Dollars%2C%20to%20our%20generall%20vse%0A%0A%20King.%20No%20more%20that%20Thane%20of%20Cawdor%20shall%20deceiue%0AOur%20Bosome%20interest%3A%20Goe%20pronounce%20his%20present%20death%2C%0AAnd%20with%20his%20former%20Title%20greet%20Macbeth%0A%0A%20Rosse.%20Ile%20see%20it%20done%0A%0A%20King.%20What%20he%20hath%20lost%2C%20Noble%20Macbeth%20hath%20wonne.%0A&ignorecase=1&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0). I am trying to get all words between 3 and 5 but haven't succeeded.

Comment: Please post all the repro data here, inside the question body. What is not working for you exactly?

Comment: I don't know what you meant by repo data. I got no matches, if that is what you are asking

Comment: The `I{3,5}` regex must be provided in the question, that is SO rules. And it won't fetch you any matches as it matches 3 to 5 consecutive `I`s. I guess you need `\b[A-Z][a-z]{3,5}\b(?=\.)` without any IgnoreCase, but not sure...

Comment: Just FYI: `r'[A-Z].{2,4}\.'` also matches `F12.`. Since you accepted the answer, I guess it is expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this produce your desired output?

```
import re

re.findall(r'[A-Z].{2,4}\.', text)
```

When `text` contains the text in your question it will produce this output:

```
['King.', 'Rosse.', 'King.', 'Rosse.', 'King.']
```

The regex pattern matches *any* sequence of characters following an initial capital letter. You can tighten that up if required, e.g. using `[a-z]` in the pattern `[A-Z][a-z]{2,4}\.` would match an upper case character followed by between 2 to 4 lowercase characters followed by a literal dot/period.

If you don't want duplicates you can use a set to get rid of them:

```
>>> set(re.findall(r'[A-Z].{2,4}\.', text))
set(['Rosse.', 'King.'])
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am also getting "wonne." in the results

Comment: @DhirajEadara Disable the ignore-case button

Comment: @DhirajEadara: yes, as Mr. E said, disable the the `IGNORECASE` button in Pythex.

Answer (score 0):

You may have your own reasons for wanting to use regexs here, but Python provides a rich set of string methods and (IMO) it's easier to understand the code using these:

```
matched_words = []
for line in open('text.txt'):
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        if word[0].isupper() and word[-1] == '.' and 3 <= len(word)-1 <=5:
            matched_words.append(word)
print matched_words
```